# Regex/R to extract string from path with version number

Tags: r, regex

I have columns with strings like this:

```
col = c("/abc/def/hdk/database/dbclient/ibm/DB2Client-V97FP02.v01/sqllib/lib64",
        "/abc/def/hdk/database/dbclient/ibm/DB2Client-V97FP02.v01/sqllib/misc", 
        "azn/external/curl-7.52.1/linux_g44.exe",
        "store/software/ep/rpg/external/python27-2.7.1/lib")
```

I want to extract the string that followed by the version number. I want the result to be like:

```
result = c("DB2Client-V97FP02.v01","DB2Client-V97FP02.v01", "curl-7.52.1", "python27-2.7.1")
```

I was able to use regex to extract just the bersion number that follows standard version `"\\d+(\\.\\d+)"` but have no idea how to tackle this problem.

Thank you

Comment: How do you plan on determining what's a version number? The first two have `\\.v\\d+`, but the other two don't

Comment: How did your attempt to solve this go ?

Comment: Exactly. I was able to use regex to extract just the bersion number that follows standard version “\\d+(\\.\\d+)” but have no idea how to tackle this problem

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Your answer for curl seems wrong, should be `"curl-7.52.1"`. I don't know how you expect to "know" that the first should be `"DB2Client-V97FP02.v01"` and not perhaps `"lib64"` (since it's text-followed-by-number, which is all that `"DB2..v01"` is).

Comment: Try `regmatches(col, regexpr("[^/]+-(?:\\w+\\.v)?\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)*", col, perl=TRUE))`

Answer (score 1):

I suggest matching all non-`/` chars, then a hyphen, then an optional group of 1+ word chars followed with `.v` and then 1+ digits followed with 1 or more repetitions of `.` and 1+ digits:

```
regmatches(col, regexpr("[^/]+-(?:\\w+\\.v)?\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)*", col, perl=TRUE))
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/XDgLyb/1) and the [regex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5B%5E%2F%5D%2B-(%3F%3A%5Cw%2B%5C.v)%3F%5Cd%2B(%3F%3A%5C.%5Cd%2B)*):

[image]

[R demo](https://ideone.com/nLP6bI):

```
col <- c("/abc/def/hdk/database/dbclient/ibm/DB2Client-V97FP02.v01/sqllib/lib64", "/abc/def/hdk/database/dbclient/ibm/DB2Client-V97FP02.v01/sqllib/misc", "azn/external/curl-7.52.1/linux_g44.exe", "store/software/ep/rpg/external/python27-2.7.1/lib")
regmatches(col, regexpr("[^/]+-(?:\\w+\\.v)?\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)*", col, perl=TRUE))
## => [1] "DB2Client-V97FP02.v01" "DB2Client-V97FP02.v01" "curl-7.52.1"           "python27-2.7.1"
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your examples, I would suggest `/\d([\d\.\-]*\d)?/`. This will match the version number from any of these. You could also change the second and third `\d` to a `\w` if you want to allow it to do alphanumeric values.